# asp:Repeater with same ID or similar

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, asprepeater

I've got an **View.ascx** page and a **View.ascx.cs** page. In my .ascx file I've got the possibility to insert a lot of Capi Denunciati (this part is made by a select menù with animal specie (like Anatra, Cavallo, Gallo, ecc...) and a lot of input text field and other two select menù. At the end, there is a button than, on click, create another field of Capi Denunciati).

This is one select menù in this Capi Denunciati

```
<select id="modDistruzioneForm" name="modDistruzioneForm" style="display: none">
  <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repModDistruzione">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <option value="<%# Eval("Key") %>">
           <%# Eval("Value") %></option>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater> 
</select>
```

Because I don't know the number of the Capi Denunciati tha User would be insert, I ask: is possibile insert this `<asp:Repeater>` more times with the same ID? If I use this way to work, in my ascx.cs file I need to call the function to popolate this repeater only on one ID (this function catch some value from DB).

Thank you for your help!

(Please don't answer "ID is unique", I know...)

Comment: Why don't you try and check!

Comment: @PawanNogariya Thank you for your answer. Because I don't know what I can try and check. Give me some ideas, please!